# Does input to constructor constitute space complexity?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Space complexity is defined as : `Auxiliary Space is the extra space or temporary space used by an algorithm.`

So whats the space complexity of the code below ? The input string `str` does not add any aux space, But the constructor does use some space.

So is the space complexity O(1) or O(n), where n is set size ?

```
public class AsymptoticNotationForSearch {

    private final Set<String> set;

    public AsymptoticNotationForSearch(Set<String> strSet) {
        this.set = strSet;
    }


    public boolean contains(String str) {
        return set.contains(str);
    }

}
```

Comment: The big-Oh space cost of this code is exactly the same as the cost of simply having a `Set<String>` local variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's O(1) - the variable set is just an object reference, the space it uses is static and does not depend on the size of the set passed in. Only if you made a copy of that set would it be O(n).